# How to handle server side error during authentication in react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

So I was making an app and in that app I have say login with facebook

For login, I am using [expo-web-browser](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/)

Here is my relevant code,

```
loginWithFacebook = async () => {
    const redirectUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL()
    const authUrl = config.backendUrl + '/auth/facebook'
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleRedirect)
    try {
        const authResult = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(authUrl, redirectUrl)
        console.log(authResult)
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleRedirect)
    } catch (err) {
  console.warn('ERROR:', err)
}
}
```

While this works, my problem is on error handling, I am using passport Js on the backend (NodeJS). On successful authentication, I am re-directing to my deep link url

```
  return res.redirect(myapplink://)
```

and currently, on error (say there is an sql connection error), I am throwing a 500 internal error

```
return res.status(error.status).send(error.message)
```

Since typically auth related events are done using `href` and not using ajaxy request, How would you typically handle the error in this situation?  I think the answer for the app and web should be identical but if not can you please suggest the way I can handle error in the app and web.

Comment: Not sure if optimal but maybe use EJS? probably someone else can suggest a better approach

Comment: What's the desired behavior when the auth fails?

Comment: if you are using expo  then why dont you use facebook and google modules of expo directly? and if you are not using expo and plain RN, then go for firebase

Comment: @Nick Modal web browser using for authentication closes and the error thrown is shown? (in error.message)

Comment: Not using expo, and don't want use Firebase because I want to allow user to connect many accounts with his profile and with Marketing Api scopes